# recursive ajax function slowing down

Tags: performance, jquery

I'm working on a jquery application.
The end user sends a request to the server, and the server creates a file with all the values, but the server only sends the x first values.

The end user can click on a button to have the x next values, or he can click on another button to have all values. 
To have all values, i've created an ajax request in a function name internGetAllValues, and in the callback function of the ajax request, i recursively call the same function (internGetAllValues) except if the user clicks on a stop button.

Then i display the number of values loaded. i can see the number of values incrementing fast at first , but then after a while it slows down. i've checked the server and it does not seem to be overwhelmed. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely skipping the values already downloaded on the server side is taking time. In other words, server side pagination logic seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Hi. you're right i had not thought of that. But i've found another culprit, refreshing the jquerymobile list takes more and more time. I'm also saving the data in a javascript array, so i guess javascript had to internally realloc some size for the array. Thanks !

So i think i'm going to alloc the right size for the javascript array from the start and i'll refresh the jquery mobile listview only when the user clicks on stop.